# Rails: Querying Postgres for JSON Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Rails (4.2) and the Postgres JSON data type to store arrays:

```
#<Mapping:0x007fa3b6263390 foo: ["bar", baz]>
```

Now I want to query for all mappings with a specific array:

```
Mapping.where(foo: ["bar", "baz"])
```

Turns out this does not work. What query can I use to find what I want? All the JSON query examples are usually for hashes, not for arrays (at least not at the top level).

Comment: There's support for an array datatype in postgres.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord has built-in [support](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) for Postgres arrays.

```
# equality
Book.where("tags = ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["fantasy", "fiction"])

# inclusion
Book.where("tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["fantasy", "fiction"])
```

There are quite a lot of array functions available, check them out [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)).